# when load one javascript library, another stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

When I reference jQuery, using the first script reference, every thing is fine, however if I just replace the closing tag  with />, **jQuery works fine!!**, however, a java script library domtab.js stop working.  that applies on FF and IE.

Why?, I don't think it is a bug that in all browsers, there is something I miss.

```
    <!--ok-->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>

    <!--Replace-->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/domtab.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot self-close a script tag. You *have to* use `</script>`.

If you use `/>`, the following text will be interpreted as the script source up to the next occurrence of `</script>`. That's why your second script does not work.

The [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) denotes script element end tags as required. This is because HTML character escaping rules are not in effect for script contents (i.e. you can use otherwise reserved characters like `<` or `&` without encoding them as `&lt;` or `&amp;`). As a result, a fixed "end contents" marker is required, which just happens to be `</script>`.

Comment: This question has further info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work